Данные гугл таблицы
Есть большая таблица, нужно чтобы при изменений даты на текущем листе в одну/несколько ячеек вставилась дата прошлого дня и данные из ячейки с листа прошлого дня, подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли вообще такое?

Вариант ниже. С обработкой ошибки на случай, если листа со вчерашней датой нет в книге.
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ДВССЫЛ("'" & ТЕКСТ($G$1-1;"DD.MM.YYYY") & "'!A1");"Листа " & ТЕКСТ($G$1-1;"DD.MM.YYYY") & " в книге нет")



Спасибо, очень помог.
